# Why does my SQL Query Reports string of 30 characters max?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, character

Whenever I run a query on SQL, it never reports more than 30 characters in a cell.

For Example,

If I needed to find Barbara Dawson's (fake name) address and I run the query:

```
select * from passes
where last = 'dawson' and first = 'barbara'
```

The results will pull Barbara's information but her street address is cutoff. Instead of reporting "1501 Buckingham Crossing Apt # 507" it reports "1501 Buckingham Crossing Apt #"

I have run multiple procedures and queries and all the reports cut off at 30 characters. I double checked the program and it is written correctly on the program but not when I pull it from SQL.

This became an issue because we create mailing lists and when addresses are incorrect in the report, it results in a bunch of returned mail and wasted resources.

Comment: I think this is an issue with the application you are using to access the database.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior when you execute the query from SSMS?

Comment: 30 is a somewhat magic number - I'd be looking through your codebase for `CAST` or `CONVERT` operators where the target type is `(n)varchar` and no length is specified.

Comment: On one of my store procedures, I see a CAST command but it is refering to dates. I don't see a varchar target anyway in the code. Forgive me, I am new to SQL

Comment: Which tool are you using in order to create the reports? SQL Report Server?

Comment: On top of what @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, I would also check the sizes (lengths) of string data types in both your database and front end application. Also check for string functions that may truncate text e.g. `LEFT` function in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance! It seems that the length in the table is set to 30 ch and cannot be adjusted. Is there a way to pull a report of columns that have more than 30 characters of data store? I think we are going to have to go into every contact and add a second address.